# How to parse Multiple Values in one Cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie that stores 5 values separated by commas in one cookie.  I'm able to retrieve the value of ExampleCookie as follows (as example):

var CookieValue = readCookie('ExampleCookie');
//returns Foo,Bar,Foo1,FooFighter,Bar2

How do I parse through CookieValue to assign individual variables such that I can assign a variable to each of the 5 parts?

I've found ways to do this with PHP but not javascript.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

use the String.split(delimiter) method

```
var array = readCookie('ExCook').split(",");
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I quickly realized this was more of a question on Split than about cookies.  Here is what i came up w/.var splits = ExampleCookie.split(",");
var slot1 = splits[0];
var slot2 = splits[1];
var slot3 = splits[2]; etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an array from string:

```
CookieParams = CookieValue.split(",");
CookieParams[0] = Foo
CookieParams[1] = Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the CookieValue into individual values in an array via the the split() method.

var valList = CookieValue.split(','); // ["Foo", "Bar", "Foo1", "FooFighter", "Bar2"]

If you then want the values to be assigned to individual variables, you would need to loop through the array and manually make the assignment.

Comment: or as cyborg86pl shows... it the list is small enough, skip the loop and directly assign to variables. Now if the list will be an arbitrary length with no or a large max, then we whip out the loop.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.stringify, and JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) are your best cleanest bets (imho)

```
var values = JSON.parse(readCookie('ExampleCookie'));

createCookie('ExampleCookie',JSON.stringify(values));
```

This has the added benefit of being able to set key values in your object/array.

Assuming you're using the functions found at [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) just ensure your cookie values stringified don't go over the [4000 char limit](http://manicode.blogspot.co.nz/2009/08/real-world-cookie-length-limits.html) found in most browsers.

Comment: what is ```readCookie('```in your example

Comment: It's in the question, a function that reads a cookie I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly realized this was more of a question on Split than about cookies. Here is what i came up w/.

```
var splits = ExampleCookie.split(","); 
var slot1 = splits[0]; 
var slot2 = splits[1]; 
var slot3 = splits[2]; etc.
```